# Can I use Map<> in query params?

Tags: java, rest, javax.ws.rs

Can I use Map in query params?
I have a number of resources for REST and I want to change list of query params in one place, I have a such source:

```
@GET
@Path("...")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String getPath(
        @PathParam("...") String path, 
        @QueryParam("headers") Map<String, String> headers // error!
```

How to use dynamic list of query params? Because headers will change in the future

Comment: and what is the error? But this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle's documentation on [extracting request parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5np/index.html), you should be able to use the `@Context` annotation to pass headers into your method:

```
@GET
@Path("...")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String getPath(
    @PathParam("...") String path, 
    @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
...
```

and then access the headers and cookies via methods on the [HttpHeaders](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) instance. I haven't tried this, but it looks like it should work.